# JavaScript event for alternate click functionality?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a UI in which I would like clicking on an object have a different function than ctrl clicking on it (or similar). This seemed to work fine on my own workstation until I tried it on a Macbook. On the laptop it seems like it triggers some form of translation lookup of the underlying text.

Question: Is there some event combination that people typically use on website UIs if you need to support two alternate clicking types and it needs to work on both a PC and a Mac?

ps. This is a GUI proof of concept demo for an algorithm and just needs to work on a browser on a Macbook as well as a Linux/Windows workstation. In other words, needs to get nowhere near production.

Comment: Control-click is the same as right-click, it triggers the `contextmenu` event.

Comment: @Barmar Really? What control key do you have? For me it just triggers a usual `click` event, with `.ctrlKey` set to `true`.

Comment: Shift+Click seems to be quite popular, similar to Ctrl+Click and Alt+Click. Make sure to prevent the default event, and make sure not to use those on link elements where your users expect their custom browser alternative behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/g4Ls93hn/2/ When I control-click I get the "menu" alert.

Comment: @Barmar Weird, what setup do you have? I'm using current Blink-based browsers on Win7, and I get "click".

Comment: I'm using Chrome on a Mac. But the Control-click = right-click mapping is pretty standard across the board on OS X.